# $l$-dependence of the group of homologically zero cycles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, algebraic-cycles, chow-groups

Consider the class map $$cl:CH^i(X)\to H^{2i}_{cont}(X,\mathbb{Z}_l(i))$$ where the RHS is the continuous etale cohomology(defined by Jannsen in his paper "Continuous etale cohomology"). In this paper he mentiones that the kernel $CH^i(X)_l^0$ might depend on $l$.

What is known about this issue? Is there an example of $X$ and two primes $l_1,l_2$ such that $CH^i(X)_{l_1}^0\neq CH^i(X)_{l_2}^0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the way it's stated, with integral cohomology, it certainly can depend on $\ell$. This is because of the occurrence of torsion classes Clearly a $p$-torsion class is sent to $0$ by this map for $\ell\neq p$, so it is sufficient to find an $\ell$-torsion class that is not sent to zero under this map.

But the Kummer exact sequence shows that for $i=1$, the kernel of the map is $\ell$-divisible. Hence any non-divisible torsion class, like a torsion point on an elliptic curve over a number field, or the canonical bundle of an Enriques surface, will do.

However with $\mathbb Q_\ell$ it may still be independent of $\ell$, depending on the base field. For algebraically closed fields it should be independent, because of the standard conjecture D which says the kernel would just be the group of cycles numerically equivalent to $0$. For arbitrary fields there are counteredamples as Mikhail Bondarko pointed out. For finitely generated fields I'm not sure.

Comment: Just a note: I don't think your elliptic curve example works, since $H^2$ will be torsion-free in that case.  The Enriques example does, though.

Comment: @DanielLitt Isn't that only true for $H^2(E_{\overline{K}}, \mathbb Z_\ell(1))$, not $H^2(E_K, \mathbb Z_\ell(1))$? The exact sequence $H^1(E_K, \mathbb G_m) \to H^1(E_K, \mathbb G_m) \to H^1(E_K, \mu_{\ell^n})$ shows that the class of an $\ell$-torsion point is nonvanishing mod $\ell^n$ for each $n$, hence nonvanishing $\ell$-adically.

Comment: Oops, didn't see that you'd written number field.  You're right of course!

Comment: This conjecture is clearly wrong in general: possibly true if the base field is finitely generated (yet I am not sure; I may be false for trivial reasons in this case also).

Comment: @MikhailBondarko I was only thinking of finitely generated base fields.

Comment: Do you have a reference for a conjecture of this sort (in this case)?

Comment: @MikhailBondarko Hmm, maybe this does not work. I was thinking of something like the Beilinson-Lichtenbaum conjecture given an isomorphism between etale and motivic cohomology, but it looks like that does not apply to $H^p(X, \mathbb Q_\ell(q))$ for $p>q$ which is what we need as here $p=2q$.

Comment: @MikhailBondarko However over function fields it could be fine as then the map will factor through a usual etale cohomology group and then independence of $\ell$ would follow from the Numerical=Homological standard conjecture - although one should check that the kernel of the map from etale to Galois cohomology is not problematic.